# copy() copying all but last element from vector to array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, copy

I'm new to c++ and programming in general.  Feel free to leave any hints, tips, or suggestions about my code!!

I am trying to copy my doubles from a vector to an array.  I used  `copy()` and it is copying all the elements except for the last.  So the last element in the array stays exactly the same as it was before I used copy.  So when I try to add the sums of the elements in the array, I don't get the correct sum.

Here is my code:

```
vector<double> myVector; 
double myArray[4];
double myDouble = 0.0;

    ...//(add elements to vector)

    copy(&myVector[0], &myVector[4], myArray);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    myDouble += myArray[i];
    if(i == 4)
        cout << "The sum of your values is " << fixed << setprecision(2) << myDouble << endl;
}
```

Thank you!  Let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: Unrelated, but you should move the printing section of your code outside of the `for` loop

Comment: Unrelated, but why would you copy from vector to array?

Comment: Use `myVector.begin() ` and `end()` instead of `&myVector[0]`. Prefer iterators over pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The call to `std::copy()` copies four elements. This seems to fill your array. Note that your array contains exactly 4 elements and the last valid index is `3`. Your vector `myVector` seems to include at least 5 elements: If it contains less then 5 elements, the expression `myVector[4]` is illegal. That said, the end iterator in a sequence always refers to the element behind the last value of the sequence, i.e., sequences are half-open: the begin is included, the end is the first element not included.

That said, you probably want to copy like this:

```
std::copy(myVector.begin(), std::min(4, myVector.size()) + myVector.begin(), myArray);
```

Of course, to get the sum of the elements in the vector you would actually use

```
double sum = std::accumulate(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), 0.0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Copy all elements from your vector this way:

```
copy(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), myArray);
```

Comment: And make sure that there are no more than 4 elements in the vector, since that's how many elements there are in the array.

Comment: yep, checking the target array is big enough is another story

Answer (score 0):

You have this code:

```
copy(&myVector[0], &myVector[4], myArray);
```

It copies 4 elements.
Now you have the decalaration of the destination array:

```
double myArray[4];
```

So the array has 4 elements.

It seems that you want to copy *all but the last element*, so copy just 3 elements:

```
copy(&myVector[0], &myVector[3], myArray);
```